# Showing Popup in Mobile Browser

Tags: html, css, wordpress, popup

I have a wordpress site and want to launch popup (iframe) only for mobile visitors and will close when visitor click the popup. Is there any idea how to implement this?

Comment: you may use plugin for that, there is good one that you can configure to show popup only for specific device

Comment: I know there is few 'paid' plugins that can be used for this, but I think it's a simple things and no need to pay for it. :(

Comment: no need for paying plugin, there is free ones

Comment: I have searched many times for it and still can't found any free plugin for it. If you have any source for it, please let me know. It will highly appreciate

Comment: what i mean, is you can pick up any plugin that allow you to add a pop up, then you can add your own code ... You just need few CSS to make a pop up only appear for mobile.

Comment: I already used XYZ Lightbox plugin to show popup both on dekstop and mobile version. What I need is "few CSS to make a pop up only appear for mobile" as you said, without pay for premium version. Please do help me.

Comment: in this case, show us the code (or the site) and what you have done so far and we will help you ;) we need to see it to give you the CSS code

Comment: What kind of code you mean? Is it the plugin code or the site code?

Comment: i mean the code of your site, or show us the site so we can see the popup and give the code to apply